# Mysql/PostgreSql getScale() return 0

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

there is a sql:

```
select
   round(usr_abnormal_record_rate, 2) as usr_abnormal_record_rate
 from
   dm_ct_xdr_lte_5g_s1u_n3_ohvd_delimit_usr_d
```

When using PostgreSQL, `ResultSetMetaData.getScale(i)`returns `0`.

But when I use MySQL, it returns current value, such as `2`.

So, how can I get the value `2` when using the PostgreSQL JDBC driver?

there is a part of my code:

```
List<ResultSet2DataTable> resultSet2DataTables = session.selectList(sqlContext.getSqlId(), alarmMapParam);
  for (ResultSet2DataTable r : resultSet2DataTables) {
        DataTable dataTable = r.getDataTable(sqlContext.getSqlId());
        DataTableImpl dataTableImpl=(DataTableImpl)dataTable;
        if (dataTableImpl!=null) {
            logger.info("execute sql: "+sqlContext.getSqlId()+", result size: "+dataTableImpl.size());
        }
        list.dataTableList.add(dataTable);
    }
```

it's more about `ResultSet2DataTable`:

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
columnCount = columnCount - cutLastField;
logger.info("processRow  columnCount=" + columnCount + ",cutLastField=" + cutLastField);
for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
    int columnIndex = i + 1;
    tableInfo.setName(metaData.getTableName(columnIndex));
    ColInfo colInfo = new ColInfo();
    colInfo.setName(metaData.getColumnName(columnIndex).toLowerCase());
    int precision = metaData.getPrecision(columnIndex);
    int scale = metaData.getScale(columnIndex);
    colInfo.setFormat(precision + "." + scale);
    colInfo.setDataType(sqlType2MyType(metaData.getColumnClassName(columnIndex), precision, scale));
    colInfos.add(colInfo);
}
```

the data type of field `usr_abnormal_record_rate` is numeric. I tried `cast(ROUND(usr_abnormal_record_rate,2) as numeric(20,2))`, but it did't work.

when using MySQL JDBC, the scale returns 2, which is -1 using PostgreSQL JDBC.

Comment: Is it using the same data type? Scale only has meaning for NUMERIC and DECIMAL ([as documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getScale(int)): _"`0` is returned for data types where the scale is not applicable."_) The PostgreSQL documentation specifies that round(double precision) results in a double precision (which doesn't have a scale), but it doesn't seem to explicitly specify that for the two-arg round.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. yes, it`s the same data type. What bores me for couple days is that MySQL JDBC returns a current result -- 0.45 for example, but PostgreSQL JDBC returns 0.0.

Comment: Then you'd better provide a complete [mre].

Comment: Please [edit] your question, don't add details in the comments

Comment: I did, but don't work.

Comment: what data type is `usr_abnormal_record_rate`?

Comment: it's numeric(12, 6)